# Applying a function to a task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I've written the following extension method on tasks

```
public static async Task<TOut> TaskMap<TIn,TOut>(this Task<TIn> task, Func<TIn,TOut> f)
{
   TIn x = await task;
   return f(x);
}
```

I'm hoping what this does is just create a new task like the original one which just applies `f` after the original task completes.

That is, `Task y = t.TaskMap(x => x)` should really be the same as `Task y = t`, barring a quick object construction and function call. It shouldn't fundamentally change when the original task is executed.

My questions are:

1. Is this function sensible and does what I intend?
2. Does it already exist?

Comment: See [`ContinueWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Related GitHub issue: [API Proposal: Then or ContinueWithResult extension method for Task](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/58692). Microsoft is not very warm at including it in the standard libraries.